# Pinning webview Certificate inside onReceivedClientCertRequest method

Tags: android, webview, pinning

Is that possible to pinning webview Certificate inside onReceivedClientCertRequest method.
I want to implement something like :

```
@Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        // Register for port 443 our SSLSocketFactory with our keystore
        // to the ConnectionManager
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
        return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
        try {
            // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
            KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            // Get the raw resource, which contains the keystore with
            // your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
            InputStream in = MyHttpClient.context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.codeprojectssl); //name of your keystore file here
            try {
                // Initialize the keystore with the provided trusted certificates
                // Provide the password of the keystore
                trusted.load(in, "YourKeystorePassword".toCharArray());
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }
            // Pass the keystore to the SSLSocketFactory. The factory is responsible
            // for the verification of the server certificate.
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
            // Hostname verification from certificate
            // http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e506
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER); // This can be changed to less stricter verifiers, according to need
            return sf;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
```

inside this method that override from webview client :

```
 @Override
    @TargetApi(21)
    public void onReceivedClientCertRequest (WebView view, ClientCertRequest request)
    {

        // By default pass to WebViewClient
        super.onReceivedClientCertRequest(view, request);
    }
```

is that possible, and is there a good example, because I can't find on google ?